# Creating an array of struct after joining/grouping in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have recently stated exploring spark.
I have the following table showing students against the books they have borrowed. The book Id is unique here.

```
|St Id|Book Id|Pages|
|----|-------|-----|
|1|1|200|
|2|2|300|
|3|3|400|
|1|4|500|
```

I need my resultant data set to be like this

```
|St Id|Books|Num Books|
|-----|-----|---------|
|1|[1,1,200],[1,4,500]|2|
|2|[2,2,300]|1|
|3|[3,3,400]|1|
```

I am able to get the num books. However I have no idea how to get the values for the Books column in the resulting table/data set.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you show what you have done? If I'm not wrong, the expected output would be to have the student id, the list of books as the second column and the third column depends on the second one based on the list you got. If that is the case, I guess using `groupBy` and then `df.withColumn("num books", size($"books"))` should do the work

Comment: All I have done is a group by on the st id column and did a count to get the num books. I have no idea how to get the books column values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `array()` and `size()` functions for this case.

**`Example:`**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df = Seq((1,1,200),(1,4,500),(2,2,300),(3,3,400)).toDF("st_id","book_id","pages")
df.groupBy("st_id").agg(collect_list(array(col("st_id"),col("book_id"),col("pages"))).alias("Books"),
size(collect_list(col("book_id"))).alias("num_books")).show(10,false)
//+-----+--------------------------+---------+
//|st_id|Books                     |num_books|
//+-----+--------------------------+---------+
//|1    |[[1, 1, 200], [1, 4, 500]]|2        |
//|2    |[[2, 2, 300]]             |1        |
//|3    |[[3, 3, 400]]             |1        |
//+-----+--------------------------+---------+
```